# How to parse "GMT+09:30" to hours, minutes

Tags: java, date, datetime, timezone-offset

How to parse "GMT+09:30" to hours, minutes by using Java? 
hours: 9.5 
minutes: 570

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish with the hours/minutes? This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). More context could help to provide a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your time work.

```
    String input = "GMT+09:30";
    ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.from(GMT_OFFSET_PARSER.parse(input));
    int offsetSeconds = offset.getTotalSeconds();
    
    double hours = (double) offsetSeconds / (double) Duration.ofHours(1).toSeconds();
    System.out.println("Hours: " + hours);
    
    long minutes = Duration.ofSeconds(offsetSeconds).toMinutes();
    System.out.println("Minutes: " + minutes);
```

Output:

> ```
> Hours: 9.5
> Minutes: 570
> ```

I used this formatter for parsing:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter GMT_OFFSET_PARSER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("OOOO", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Your string, `GMT+09:30`, denotes an offset from GMT. In this example the local time being nine and a half hours ahead of GMT, as is the case in parts of Australia. A `DateTimeFormatter` can parse such an offset much the way it parses a date and/or time. I am specifying the format pattern `OOOO` following this part from the documentation:

| Symbol | Meaning | Presentation | Examples |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| … | … | … | … |
| O | localized zone-offset | offset-O | GMT+8; GMT+08:00; UTC-08:00 |

For offset-O we are further informed:

> **Offset O**: … Four letters outputs the full form, which is localized
> offset text, such as 'GMT, with 2-digit hour and minute field,
> optional second field if non-zero, and colon, for example 'GMT+08:00'. …

I noticed that `Locale.ENGLISH` recognized the text `GMT`. I figure that other locales may do the same or require `UTC` instead.

I trust there to be a whole number of minutes, so the `Duration` class of java.time can make this conversion on its own. Since the hours need not be a whole number, we need to make this conversion ourselves. I simply divide the seconds of the offset by the number of seconds in an hour.

**Documentation link:** [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: Thank you for the code. But I don't understand why do you use the pattern "0000", Locale.ENGLISH. Would you please explain it to me?

Comment: I just checked the documentation. :-) I have edited and added some explanation. If you have further questions, please follow up, I am here to help.